# How to install firefox in heroku?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, heroku, selenium-firefoxdriver

Can someone help me on how to install *Firefox* in *heroku*?

We have created an app and wanted to do run *Selenium Java* program which will get executed in the Firefox browser.

When I searched on the Internet i came across this [link](https://github.com/bensomers/firefox-buildpack), but I am not sure whether it installs Firefox in Heroku, or whether there are any costs involved.

Answer (score 0):

The [Firefox buildpack](https://github.com/bensomers/firefox-buildpack) you mention is probably not a bad way to go. It will increase your slug size, but not by much. But when using it, make sure you follow the [Heroku guide for using multiple buildpacks for an app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app). If you are using Java, you will also need the [Java buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java) as you last/final buildpack.

An alternative to the Firefox buildpack is the [Apt buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt), which would allow you to install arbitrary apt packages, such as firefox.

Comment: When i install firefox buildpack, my application is not getting deployed and web-runner is not created in targe/dependency folder. Basically i have a java file which will execute the code in the firefox browser with FireFoxWebDriver. Please let me know how to install firefox on heroku and invoke the webdrive to open and close the browser whenever it is required.

Comment: The Firefox buildpack is no longer maintained, and not a valid solution. The project maintainer [commented](https://github.com/bensomers/firefox-buildpack/issues/1) about not being able to get Firefox to run on Heroku.